# Not able to find any elements identified on the webpage after the InternetExplorer browser is launched through Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webdriver

I am using `selenium Webdriver 2.24` to automate a website. As soon as the **IE browser** gets launched using the webdriver, the driver is not able find any fields present (such as Text boxes, buttons  etc ) on the page and is throwing `unable to locate the element`.

I used `Visual Studio C#` to write the code. The same works fine on Firefox.

**Note:** When I try `Driver.Pagesource` ; It returns a Null value

Possible reasons/suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: Please post some code for others to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have had problems with 2.24 too--try either going back to 2.23 or move on up to 2.25.